# Numerical evaluation of the first (K) and second (E) complete elliptic integrals

Tags: numerical-methods, elliptic-integrals

To get a numerical evaluation of the first (K) and second (E) complete elliptic integrals:

$$K(k)=\int_0^1\frac{dt}{(1-t^2)^{1/2}(1-k^2t^2)^{1/2}}, \ \ \ \ \ E(k)=\int_0^1\frac{(1-k^2t^2)^{1/2}}{(1-t^2)^{1/2}}dt$$

in a left neighbourhood of the point $k=1$. What numerical methods do you recommend to get a "good" approximation of K and E in a left neighbourhood of the point $k=1$?

Comment: This is on topic here, but [scicomp.se] may be able to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\quad$ Use the trigonometric-integral expressions for [these functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), expand them using the [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), switch the order of summation and integration, then make use of [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals) in order to arrive at the well-known but slow-converging infinite series for each, also presented in the article. Use the recurrence relation $T_n=\bigg(\dfrac{2n-1}{2n}k\bigg)^2\cdot a_n\cdot T_{n-1}$, where $a_n=1$ for $K(x)$, and $\dfrac{2n-3}{2n-1}$ for $E(x)$.